# Three-way operator <=> return struct with implicit conversion function

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, implicit-conversion, c++20, spaceship-operator

Consider the following useless code:

```
struct S{
  constexpr operator int() const { return 0; }
  constexpr auto operator<=>(S) const { return *this; }
};

static_assert(S{} <= S{});
```

Clang and MSVC accept this code but GCC [rejects](https://godbolt.org/z/h689Pc) it with an error message:

```
error: no match for 'operator<=' (operand types are 'S' and 'int')
```

Which compiler is right? How `operator<=` is synthesized from `operator<=>`?

Comment: I think returning `*this` from `<=>` is the problem here. It's a strange thing to do btw, may I ask why you wrote that?

Comment: @cigien To be honest, I don’t know why I did this. As I said, this is just a useless program. :D

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, nothing wrong with that :) It's an interesting question.

Comment: Just to be sure, does `S{} <= 0` compile ok?  Or does it try to recursively call `operator <=>` and fail because the second operand type `int` doesn't match `S` ?

Comment: @BenVoigt `S{} <= 0` compiles just fine.

Comment: @cigien: Yes it seems like something must be going wrong with g++'s logic for "Rewritten candidates for the operator @ are not considered in the context of the resulting expression".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [over.match.oper] ([3.4.1](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.oper#3.4.1) and [8](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.oper#8)):

> For the relational ([expr.rel]) operators, the rewritten candidates include all non-rewritten candidates for the expression x <=> y.

and

> If a rewritten `operator<=>` candidate is selected by overload resolution for an `operator @`, `x @ y` is interpreted as [...] `(x <=> y) @ 0` [...], using the selected rewritten `operator<=>` candidate. Rewritten candidates for the `operator @` are not considered in the context of the resulting expression.

So for the expression `S{} <= S{}` the selected operator will be `S::operator<=>(S) const` and the expression will be rewritten as `(S{} <=> S{}) <= 0`.  In the rewritten expression the types of the operands are `S` and `int`, for which the built-in `operator<=(int, int)` will be selected.  So ultimately the expression (after converting `S` to an `int`) will result in `0 <= 0`, which is `true`.

In conclusion Clang and MSVC are right in this case, and GCC seems to fail in interpreting `(S{} <=> S{}) <= 0` as a call to the built-in operator (notice the error message reading `operand types are 'S' and 'int'`).  If you change the condition in the `static_assert` to be the rewritten expression `(S{} <=> S{}) <= 0`, then [all three compilers accept it](https://godbolt.org/z/rGfjMT).

Comment: Make sense. +1. Is `return *this` from `<=>` well-formed?

Comment: @康桓瑋 I couldn't find any restrictions for the return type of `operator<=>`, so it should be.  The only requirement for the return type (when using it for relational operators) is that comparing it to zero should be well-formed.

Answer (score 0):

[C++20 support in GCC is still experimental](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx20), so while it [does support](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) the [three-way operator](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1185r2.html), your `static_assert` is failing because the other compilers are auto inferring the `<=` operator from the `<=>` operator, while GCC seems to be more pedantic in its interpretation of the standard, and since you do not have the `<=` operator directly, the compiler is then emitting a compile time error because it can't find the `<=` operator.

If you add the `<=` operator, the code works, example:

```
struct S{
  constexpr operator int() const { return 0; }
  constexpr auto operator<=>(S) const { return *this; }
  constexpr bool operator<=(S) { return true; }
};

static_assert(S{} <= S{});
```

Additionally, if you change your assert to be the three way operator, the test fails on all compilers, example:

```
struct S{
  constexpr operator int() const { return 0; }
  constexpr auto operator<=>(S) const { return *this; }
};

static_assert(S{} <=> S{});
```

Furthermore, since the three-way operator is expected to *essentially* return a negative, zero, or positive value (really returning an ordering), returning `*this` is likely converting the value to something that Clang and MSVC interpret as a `true` value for the assert, while GCC could be converting it to a `false` value, and thus the assert fails.

If you change the return type to any negative value (even `-0`) or a zero value, the assert passes on all compilers, additionally if you change the value to any positive value above 0 the assert fails on all compilers.

You could change the three-way operator to cast `*this` to an `int` which would call `operator int` and return 0, which would then cause the assert to pass, example:

```
constexpr auto operator<=>(S) const { return static_cast<int>(*this); }
```

So to answer directly:

> Which compiler is right?

In my experience with GCC, it tends to interpret the language very pedantically and err on the side of caution when it comes to a language specification that *might* be ambiguous in the face of an odd code snippet (like yours).

To that end, the other compilers *might* be too loose in their interpretation of the language or GCC *might* be too strict in this particular case.

Either way, even though this code is "useless," anyone who is running into something like this who is targeting all 3 compilers should probably try to be as pedantic as possible with this type of code, though that might necessarily defeat the purpose of the code in this case, unfortunately.

Comment: `static_assert(S{} <=> S{})` fails as for `4 <=> 4`, it should be `S{} <=> S{} == 0` orderings don't have be convertible to bool, (but comparable with 0).

Comment: @Jarod42 yes, you are correct in that it is a comparison value returning an ordering, but I was referring to the assert, which _is_ a true/false value, failing in GCC for some reason on its interpretation of the three way operator in the context of the code posted.

Comment: `static_assert(S{} <=> S{} <= 0);` is [accepted](https://godbolt.org/z/6Kq6o7) by the 3 compilers. and `S{} <= S{}` and `S{} <=> S{} <= 0` "should" be "equivalent".

Comment: https://eel.is/c++draft/ should be good enough as free reference.

Comment: @Jarod42 I agree with you; but that doesn't answer the question or give any more information as to _why_ GCC is interpreting the code the way it is, especially since they expressly state C++20 support is experimental. Not trying to be confrontational, especially since I have no affiliation with GCC, Clang or MSVC, but your comments seem to be trying to assert something in the negative??

Comment: I don't know which compiler is correct or not (as gcc is the only one to disagree with others...). I think that `S{} <=> S{} <= 0` is more relevant than adding `operator <=` or checking `bool(S{}<=>S{})`. but indeed neither answer the question. I think that answer has unrelated paragraphs, (and also doesn't answer OP, some parts might be good comment though).

Comment: "since you do not have the `<= operator` directly, the compiler is then emitting a compile-time error because it can't find the `<=` operator." I think this is wrong, I don't have `<= operator` but I **do** have `<=> operator`, so the GCC should synthesize for me, but somehow it failed when calling the synthesized one. Noticed that the error message is: `no match for 'operator<=' (operand types are 'S' and 'int')`, not `no match for 'operator<=' (operand types are 'S' and 'S')`.